# D3 V4 General Update Pattern for Pack Layout

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use General Pattern to update my Pack Layout but have not been successful. Below is my fiddle. So when Randomize Data is clicked the data should be updated.

Here is my full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krb5L6gr/).

```
function update() {
    root = d3.hierarchy(data)
      .sum(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.value - a.value;
      });

    var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack(root).descendants())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node";
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
      });

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      });

    node.filter(function(d) {
      return !d.children;
    }).append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.3em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only have the "enter" selection. You're missing an "update" selection (and eventually an "exit" selection).

The "update" selection can be something like this:

```
var nodeUpdate = g.selectAll(".node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });;

var circleUpdate = nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
    });
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/or7pLnjp/